# Connecting Delphi 10.1 to Interbase XE7 Desktop in the Rad Studio Development Environment

Tags: delphi, database-connection, interbase, delphi-10.1-berlin

I wanted to use the Desktop version of IB XE7 in my development environment but can't get the connection to work.

The original app had used a full server version of IB and I now wanted to run the app on a lower cost single PC type application and selected the IB Desktop version.

The Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin is running on a W7 64bit Virtual machine.
FireDac is the database connection component.
IB XE7 Desktop is the database server on the development PC.

Target for the application is a VM with W7 32bit, with another IB XE7 Desktop on that VM.

I can build the 32 bit app and it will connect to the IB XE7 Desktop on the target PC (running W7 32bit in a VM) after changing the FireDac connection component protocol field to 'local' instead of TCP/IP, something I read in Stack Overflow.

What I can't get to work is the database connection in the development environment.

I first installed the 64 bit version of IB, then removed it and tried the 32 bit version with the same result.

After reading up on some connection problems online, I tried putting 'gds_db' and 'localhost/gds_db' in the server name field, but it still didn't work, although it did change the error.

---

Error - with nothing in the server name

---

[FireDAC][Phys][IB]unavailable database.

---

---

Error after putting 'gds_db' in the server name

---

[FireDAC][Phys][IB]Unable to complete network request to host "gds_db".

Failed to locate host machine.

The specified name was not found in the hosts file or Domain Name Services..

---

First tried 64 bit IB installed, then removed all gsd files found and then the Registry entries, and installed the 32bit version. Problem still persisted.

Note: Database Workbench 5 connects  OK to the database on the same VM.

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks.

James F.

Comment: Two things: a) You need to check the actual instance name of the server.  iirc, the "sawn off" versions of IB use something other than gds_db.  b) look in the `services` file in \windows\system32\drivers\etc.  It should contain an entry like "gds_db           3050/tcp                           # InterBase Server" naming the server instance.

Comment: Btw, you might try seeing if you can get a connection using the IBX components.  I can connect to a local IB XE7 server by setting the IBConnection's database name to 'LocalHost:D:\Delphi\Interbase\Databases\MA.GDB'

Comment: .GDB is a bad filename extension starting with winXP

Comment: @Arioch'The:  Maybe, but works fine for me in Win10.

Comment: waiting for the fist OS crash - then it will overwrite your database file with the archived one.

Comment: What is Desktop edition? Is it like Firebird Embedded? Because https://www.embarcadero.com/ru/products/interbase/product-editions explicitly claims Desktop Edition does not have stand-alone "TCP Listening server"! So any connection using anything but direct file name would fail

Comment: James, which specific IB features do you use ? If you want to cut costs consider Firebird server - during Interbase version 6 time the original developers left EMBT (then Borland) and started independent server development. If you did not invested heavily into post-v.6 features, the switch might be a realistic choice.

Comment: @MartynA  www.translate.ru -> http://www.ibase.ru/ibfaq/#xp

Comment: I checked that Martyn, that entry is there as well as the developer edition which I now commented out. Did not make any difference when I try and open the connection.

Comment: James - desktop edition does not use TCP according to documentation linked above. Try Firebird.

Answer (score 2):

I remember it being quite a performance to get Delphi XE8 + Seattle working with IB XE7,
in particular I kept getting the "unavailable database" error when trying to connect from 
inside the IDE.  Note: the following are things I found necessary to get Delphi working with a local instance of the full IB XE7 package.  Requirements for the Developer and Desktop editions very probably differ, hopefully in ways explained in their documentation.

Some of the things to check are:

1. Check in the Windows Services app that the server is running.

   My server shows up as

   Interbase XE7 Server gds_db

As you can see, the Services app should tell you the name of the server.

2. If you want to connect to it via TPC/IP check that you have an entry
   in your \windows\system32\drivers\etc\service file like this

   gds_db           3050/tcp                           # InterBase Server

   Hash-sign developer_ibxe7           3054/tcp                 # InterBase Server

The line containing developer_ibxe7 should start with a #, but SO won't display that for some reason.  Anyway, that line is commented out because it refers to a developer edition I installed at some point.

3. Check that your OS environment contains an entry like this one

   INTERBASE=d:\ibxe7

If it isn't, add it and reboot the machine.

In my case, d:\ibxe7 is the top-level folder in which I have IB XE7 installed.

With those things set up/checked start a new Delphi project in the IDE, add an IBConnection to it, and set its `DatabaseName` to a local IB database.  For me, specifying

LocalHost:D:\Delphi\Interbase\Databases\MA.GDB

works fine.  Then, see if you can set the Connected property to True.  If you can't,
leave a comment and I'll see what else I can remember.

Comment: embarcadero.com/ru/products/interbase/product-editions explicitly claims Desktop Edition does not have stand-alone "TCP Listening server"

Comment: @JamesFergus:  Glad you got it working, but what change(s) in your set-up made the difference?

Comment: After chencking that it was listed in the services file and commenting out the developer edition with # I had then tried to open/activate the connection and it failed. I then re-booted the OS in case the file was read to memory. At this stage the FireDac connection component had the server field set to gds_db and the connection failed. I then cleared the server field and the connection could sucessfully be switched to active.

Comment: After chencking that it was listed in the services file and commenting out the developer edition with # I had then tried to open/activate the connection and it failed. I then re-booted the OS in case the file was read to memory. At this stage the FireDac connection component had the server field set to gds_db and the connection failed. I then cleared

Comment: @JamesFergus:  Well, what is the server field set to now that it connects successfully?

Comment: Sorry about the duplication. I got into some bother with too many characters in the edit. I cannot be certain what was the exact think that worked as on all the recent changes I had a value in the FD server field. Rem I also deleted the interbase related lines in the Tools/Options/Environment Variables Over-rides section. Possibly commenting out the dev edition in the services file?  These bloody connections are such a trial when you think you are making a simple transition.  You really feel on your own when you are relying on the Embarcadero support. Thanks again for your prompt support.

Comment: The server field is blank